# Vue router params undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

i use this code

Hi guys i use this code for a simple route param but somehow i get an undefined in the url

```
 const router = useRouter();
  const navigateToQuiz = () => {
    router.push(/quiz/${quizcard.id});
  };

  const quizcard = ref([
    {
      id: 1,

    }
```

,  router file

```
  {
      path: "/quiz/:id",
      name: "quiz",
      component: QuizView,
    },
```

I use navigateToQuiz in a list

```
   <li
            @click="navigateToQuiz"
            v-for="quiz in quizcard"
            :key="quiz.name"
            class="col-span-1 flex flex-col divide-y divide-gray-200 rounded-lg bg-white text-center shadow"
          >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you need to write `quizcard.value` first because you are using a ref. Then to access the id, since it’s an object in an array, get the object by index then you can access the id property: `quizcard.value[0].id`

Also make sure you use backticks.

**EDIT**
Based on what you are trying to achieve it looks like this is the right implementation

```js
const router = useRouter();

const navigateToQuiz = id => {
 router.push(`/quiz/${id}`);
};

const quizCards = ref([{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }])

// refs are unwrapped in template so you dont need .value here
<li v-for="quizCard in quizCards">
  <button @click="navigateToQuiz(quizCard.id)">click me</button>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort to answer. I tried it but now the route will always go to 1. So id:2 will also go to page 1. How come?

Comment: Because based on the code you provided there is only one object in the array.

Comment: Inside of your v-for you can pass the quizcard id to your function

Comment: Sorry for that. It are link multiply. 2,3,4. Etc

Comment: Thanks very much!! Much appreciate it. I am still learning this a lot. Any docs you used for this fix? Or out of your head?

Comment: That's just the way you would do it. maybe review the docs a bit here https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html